# File perm bits in octal on Linux in Go

Tags: go, file-permissions

I am trying to get file permission bits in Octal representation.
The below code prints it as string. Is there an API to print in Octal
or int?

```
import "os"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    m, _ := os.Stat("test.go")
    perm := m.Mode().Perm()
    fmt.Println(perm)
}
```

```
$:~/gocode/ws/gocode$ go run perm.go 
-rw-rw-r--
@:~/gocode/ws/gocode$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fi, err := os.Stat("test.go")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    perm := fi.Mode().Perm()
    fmt.Println(perm)
    fmt.Printf("%o\n", perm)
    fmt.Printf("%#o\n", perm)
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(perm), 8))
    fmt.Println("0" + strconv.FormatUint(uint64(perm), 8))
}
```

Output:

```
-rw-rw-r--
664
0664
664
0664
```